# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setHyperlinkStyle(String) from the type XHTMLImporter

Tags: java

Currently I'm using `doxc4j version 3.2.1`

The default argument for the method `setHyperlinkStyle()` is "Hyperlink".

So basically it would look like this in my code:

```
XHTMLImporter.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");
```

Can someone explain why I got error: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setHyperlinkStyle(String) from the type XHTMLImporter`

While it is working fine when using some previous version.

Comment: I guess you'll need to create an XHTMLImporter object and call it on that.

Comment: the XHTMLImporter is an interface so I can't instantiate an object from this ..

Comment: In that case you'll need a instance of an object that implements XHTMLImporter, your code is statically calling a method on an interface hence the error.

Comment: There is a class which implement this interface. Its name is XHTMLImporterImpl but I can't find this class in the API. Some source code found on Github, they can import that class to the file but I can't import this class as i can't see it in the downloaded package. You can see it here https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertInXHTMLFile.java

Comment: If XHTMLImporter is an interface then this code couldn't work in any previously version. I have checked that source lever is set in this project to 1.5. The only way it could works is with java 8 with defaults methods in interfaces. So please, double check what was you doing in previously versions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an instance of `XHTMLImporter`, instead of trying to use a method in a static context.

```
XHTMLImporter xi = new XHTMLImporter();
xi.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");
```

and use `xi` where you need it

Answer (score 0):

And the other thing you can do, since you say that XHTMLImporter is an interface is that you can instantiate an anonymous class that implements the interface, and then call the hyperlink style from there.  I would read the documentation for the new version of your library though.  it sounds like they changed their API, and just naïvely trying to make stuff work could lead you down rabbitholes of stuff not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example extracted of project samples folder in github.

```
        XHTMLImporter xHTMLImporter= null;
    Class<?> xhtmlImporterClass = null;
    try {
        xhtmlImporterClass = Class.forName("org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl");
        Constructor<?> ctor = xhtmlImporterClass.getConstructor(WordprocessingMLPackage.class);
        xHTMLImporter = (XHTMLImporter) ctor.newInstance(pkg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("docx4j-XHTMLImport jar not found. Please add this to your classpath.");
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return xhtmlError(sdtParent, docContainer, docfrag, "Missing XHTML Handler!");
    }
```

This link found uses of XHTMLImporter, you can found more examples.
https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=xhtmlimporter

If you can't use XHTMLImportImporterImpl try to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```